# Affine manifold and topology

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, connections

I consider an affine manifold $(M,\nabla)$, i.e. $\nabla$ is flat and torsion-free, such that:

1. $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R\times\Sigma$ with $\Sigma$ a *closed* 3-manifold.
2. There exists a Lorentzian metric $\boldsymbol  g$ on $M$, whose Levi-Civita connection $\nabla_{\boldsymbol g} \not= \nabla$ is complete, but a priori, I do not impose $\nabla$ to be complete. This second hypothesis is present because I study this problem in the context of general relativity, with an additional flat torsion-free connection.

What constraints do we have on the topology of $\Sigma$?
I ask the question with and without the second hypothesis.

To my knowledge, in the case where the connection $\nabla$ is globally compatible with a metric $\boldsymbol{g}'$ (hence the connection is Levi-Civita for $\boldsymbol{g}'$, and $\boldsymbol{\rm Riem}(\nabla) = \boldsymbol{\rm Riem}(\boldsymbol{g}') = 0$), this constrains the universal cover of $\Sigma$ to be the Euclidean space $\mathbb E^3$ (i.e. its Thurston geometry is the Euclidean geometry).

But, since not all torsion-free connections are globally Levi-Civita (or are they in this case?), I do not know if this topological constraint is valid in that case?